# best practice to use or not to overuse prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't see developers like to use prototype in JS unless the scale of the app is huge. It's because they avoid overuse of prototype function?

any simpler way of writing below logic?

```
function Dog (breed) {
  this.breed = breed;
};

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log("Woof");
};

var buddy = new Dog("golden Retriever");
buddy.bark();

var snoopy = new Dog("Beagle");
snoopy.bark();
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy simpler way to rewrite above code using prototype, it work when I put the dog.prototype.bark within the Dog constructor function, do you know why?

Comment: Your implementation is fine; it's better to put shared methods on the prototype instead of the instance.

Comment: @elclanrs it's not ok to put within the constructor? but why it work and have the same result?

Comment: Because when you add a function to the constructor you attach it to each and every instance individually. When you add it to the prototype you share the method with all instances.

Comment: @elclanrs that make sense.. if it's within the constructor function scope, it wastes memory right?

Comment: As general rule if the method uses `this` it belongs to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
function Dog (breed) {
  this.breed = breed;
};

Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log("Woof");
};
```

**Advantages:**

1. If you create more objects of `Dog`, the objects will be created faster since the `bark` is already defined in prototype, it will be set in the new object as well.

**Disadvantages:**

1. It cannot protect the data members. Since, the function is defined separately from other data members, it cannot be in closure scope.

**Method 2**

```
function Dog (breed) {
  this.breed = breed;
  this.bark = function() {
     console.log(this.breed);
  };
};
```

**Disadvantages:**

1. Every time you create an object, the function has to be created. So, performance overhead.
2. Since, `breed` is added to the object itself directly, it is accessible via the object. So, no protection for data.

**Method 3**

```
function Dog (breed) {
  this.bark = function() {
     console.log(breed);
  };
};
```

**Advantages**

1. With the help of closures, you can access `breed` within the object, but that cannot be accessed outside the object. So, protection to data.
2. No extra variable :)

**Disadvantages:**

1. Every time you create an object, the function has to be created. So, performance overhead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Dog (breed) {//this stuff is private :)
  this.breed = breed;

    return { //public api
        bark: function(){
            console.log("Woof");
        }
    }
};
```

The advantage of this pattern is it offers privacy.

Comment: It doesn't protect bark, but `breed`

Comment: But why use `this`? Why not create a new variable?

Comment: @theforutheye isnt that what i said?

Comment: *"The advantage of this pattern is it offers privacy."* And the disadvantage is increased memory usage, that `instanceof` doesn't work, that deep-copying such objects doesn't work, and probably more things.

Comment: Why create a variable at all? If you're going to use closures then `breed` as an argument will be captured in the closure when referenced.

Comment: @FelixKling This pattern is being used by yahoo and jquery to name a few.

Comment: I know, it looks like the revealing module pattern. And using it for a *module* is OK. But it's not suitable if you want to create multiple instances of the constructor function. There are always edge cases of course, but the disadvantages exist, whether "big names" use this pattern or not ;)

Comment: @AustinAllover the code above is not to demo how prototype work right? what I can see is just a method in a constructor. and I don't understand what you two is arguing about.